# mysqli shows file doesn't exist event though it does

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

I am running the following piece of code to dump a csv into a database table and I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.queryadmin.com/986/use-mysql-load-data-local-infile/) to make sure that I am doing it the right way but I keep on getting the following error even though my file exists

File 'http:/localhost/dashboardapp/uploads/admin.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)

```
                $this->db->truncate($this->table_name);                 

                $query_name = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"
            . $file_path . 
            "' INTO TABLE `"
            . $this->table_name . 
             "` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
             IGNORE 1 LINES 
             (@mytimestamp,curr_property,curr_property_cost,day_property,day_property_cost,curr_solar_generating,curr_solar_export,day_solar_generated,day_solar_export,curr_chan1,curr_chan2,curr_chan3,day_chan1,day_chan2,day_chan3)
             SET time_stamp=STR_TO_DATE(@mytimestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i')";

      $link = mysqli_init();

        if (!$link) {

            die('mysqli_init failed');
        }

        if (!mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true)) {

            die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE failed');
        }

        if (!mysqli_real_connect($link, 'localhost', 'root', 'rolemodel', 'dashboard')) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        } 

        $result = $link->query($query_name);

        if (!$result) {

             printf("%s\n", mysqli_error($link));

        }
```

I am not really sure on how to proceed as i have looked for resources but havent found any yet

Comment: Is it really `http:/localhost/` with one slash / after http? In that case, that would be the issue.

Comment: It seems a problem with `file_path` echo the `$query_name` and show what it has. Seems it has `http:/localhost/dashboardapp/uploads/admin.csv` and does not correct (see first comment from @JuhaUntinen

Comment: Make sure you reference your paths to files using PHP server variables, ie. $_SERVER. To avoid the problem stated by @Juha

Comment: i am using codeigniters base_url() in this manner

$base = base_url();
      
$file_path =  $base.'/uploads/'. $current_user.'.csv';

Comment: On echo i get the same thing, wonder why it is so

Comment: Provide a filesystem path, not a url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments guys, the problem was with the path as mentioned, I used codeigniter so I used FCPATH variable and it worked.